# Changing yAxes ticks max value cut off half chart from top

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I should be able to set chart with custom y axes tick max value and I do but my chart cut off after:

I have an api for values that return array that has like `['12','34','78','31']`
I get `Math.max(...['12','34','78','31']) // 78` and set `ticks.max = 78 + (78/10) = 88 // as max + 10%`

After that when I try to re-render chart, I get cut out from top of chart like on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0le.jpg

Just if I use 4 times as max value or 4x78, where I get full chart view. There are no other elements that are hiding chart.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Post your code, better create a fiddle